# Slow script execution

Tags: shell-script, scripting, su

I have a strange problem...

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SECONDS=0

lock_file=/tmp/$0.lock

[ -e $lock_file ] && exit

touch $lock_file

echo "<<<db2_hadr_check>>>"
instances=( db2inst1 db2inst2 )

plog() {
        lfile=/tmp/$0.log

        echo "[`date +%T`] $1" >> $lfile
}

for instance in "${instances[@]}"; do
        plog "get dbname for instance $instance"
        name=$(su - $instance -c 'echo $dbname')
        plog "get hadr info for instance $instance"
        arr=($(su - $instance -c 'db2pd -db $dbname -hadr | egrep -i "HADR_CONNECT_STATUS |HADR_LOG_GAP" | cut -d "=" -f 2'))
        plog "check result for instance $instance"

        s=${arr[0]}
        lg=${arr[1]}

        [ -z $s ] && s="DISCONNECTED"
        [ -z $lg ] && lg=0

        plog "return result for instance $instance"

        #dbname hadr_conn_status log_gap
        echo "$name $s $lg"
done
plog "Execution time: $SECONDS"
plog "############################################################"
rm $lock_file
```

I manualy run this script on my test server (Fedora release 21)...

Log from my manual run:

```
[11:46:36] get dbname for instance db2inst1
[11:46:37] get hadr info for instance db2inst1
[11:46:37] check result for instance db2inst1
[11:46:37] return result for instance db2inst1
[11:46:37] get dbname for instance db2inst2
[11:46:38] get hadr info for instance db2inst2
[11:46:39] check result for instance db2inst2
[11:46:39] return result for instance db2inst2
[11:46:39] Execution time: 3
[11:46:39] ############################################################
```

After this, I added this check in my monitor server (nagios + check_mk). If I run check_mk_agent (which then call my script) I get this execution times:

```
real    0m2.923s
user    0m0.755s
sys     0m1.982s
```

This is OK.

Here is my problem...

Log from execution with check_mk server:

```
[11:48:38] get dbname for instance db2inst1
[11:49:04] get hadr info for instance db2inst1
[11:49:30] check result for instance db2inst1
[11:49:30] return result for instance db2inst1
[11:49:30] get dbname for instance db2inst2
[11:49:55] get hadr info for instance db2inst2
[11:50:21] check result for instance db2inst2
[11:50:21] return result for instance db2inst2
[11:50:21] Execution time: 103
[11:50:21] ############################################################
```

when this script is called from check_mk (nagios) it runs for **103 seconds**!

Can someone explain that?

---

**Additional info #1:**

check_mk server use xinetd to execute check_mk_agent on host

config file (/etc/xinetd.d/check_mk):

```
service check_mk
{
        type           = UNLISTED
        port           = 6556
        socket_type    = stream
        protocol       = tcp
        wait           = no
        user           = root
        server         = /usr/bin/check_mk_agent

        log_on_success =

        disable        = no
}
```

/etc/pam.d/su:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

---

**Additional info #2:**

After @Lambert comment I did this:

On nagios server in /etc/hosts I added db2 server IP 
On db2 server /etc/hosts I added nagios server IP

I tried 2 more things:

On **nagios** server:

Command:

```
time ssh root@db2server /usr/bin/check_mk_agent
```

Result:

```
...

real    0m5.917s
user    0m0.025s
sys     0m0.028s
```

Command:

```
time telnet db2server 6556
```

Result:

```
...

real    0m51.859s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.014s
```

I ran this multiple times with the same results...

On db2server in **/var/log/messages** I found this:

```
Oct 30 14:48:55 db2server su: (to db2inst1) root on pts/0 <- 1. command
Oct 30 14:50:59 db2server su: (to db2inst1) root on none  <- 2. command
```

---

**Additional info #3:**

Command:

```
time ssh root@db2server telnet localhost 6556
```

Result:

```
real    0m7.510s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.034s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems that each `su - $instance...` is taking ~25 seconds when nagios calls it; is your `su` configured to do some extra logging or lookups? `cat /etc/pam.d/su` to see what's configured...

Comment: @jeffschaller I add /etc/pam.d/su config file... do you see something strange in it?

Comment: maybe its waiting for a password. why do you quote some expansions and not other expansions?

Comment: @mikeserv if it wait for a password it won't give me any result after 100s, but except for time difference is all the same. This is the only expansion...

Comment: What happens when you call the check directly from nagios using a terminal session (ie. check_nrpe or check_mk) twice, right after eachother. Is the second run faster than the first run? If the second run is much faster, the issue is probably name resolving because the host record is coming from the client cache during the second run. Try to add the nagios host to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: @lambert I edited my question based on your comment...

Comment: @Wolfy, What is the result of `time ssh root@db2server telnet localhost 6556`?

Comment: @Lambert I edited my question with additional info (#3)

Comment: So, check_mk is doing well, but (x)inetd is slow when called from remote. I still suspect that name resolving is a possible issue here. Can you confirm that the client (nagios host) can be resolved from host db2server? Or try adding the nagios host to the `/etc/hosts` file on host db2server and see if that helps. Your SSH configuration on db2server can be configured with `UseDNS no` so using SSH is fast, and (x)inetd is slow (because it is performing name lookups).

Comment: @Lambert sorry for my late response. I added all hosts (nagios, db2server) in /etc/hosts to both servers. Same results :( can xinted be configured to not use DNS?